# Is logic universe-dependent?

Tags: epistemology, reference-request, ontology, physics

Is logic (logic rules, arithmetic and logic inference) universe-dependent or not?

In other words: are logic rules ultimately physical laws of the universe (as gravity, quantum laws and electromagnetism are) or are them not?

Can this question ever be ever answered, either logically or experimentally?

Are there any related papers or books in this regard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is logics (logic rules, arithmetic and logic inference) universe-dependent or not.

Possibly, but we have only one universe, so its certainly not amenable to physical experiment.

> In other words: are logic rules ultimately physical laws of the universe (as gravity, quantum laws and electromagnetism are) or are them not?

According to Wittgensteins *Tractatus*, the facts of the physical worlds, and natural laws occupy only a small place in the space of all logical possibilities; and these possibilities are the horizons of our vision.

However, according to Kant logic is not in the world (noumena) but in phenomena; Wittgenstein doesn't say where as he doesn't specify the location of logic. He also says there may be unlogical worlds, but we haven't the capacity to imagine them.

> Can this question ever be ever answered, either logically or experimentally?

Not experimentally; perhaps philosophically, that is with the aid of reason or logic. But then we may have more than one answer.

> Are there any related papers or books in this regard?

I wouldn't read the *Tractatus*, as its a difficult and obscure book written in a carefully cryptic and aphoristic style. *Logicomix* is much easier, its a graphic novel, and what it covers logic in the 20C when that area was kicked off by Frege.